# Unable to create Azure search service through terraform and AZ CLI with Standard3 High density SKU but getting the error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-cli, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to create an azure search service through terraform but it is not supported through standard3 High Density SKU. Subsequently, I am trying to create it with AZ CLI but getting the error as"ERROR: Unrecognized arguments: --hosting-mode highDensity". How to resolve this error and create a search service with S3HD SKU?

I Passed the AZ CLI command to create an Azure Search Service with S3HD Sku but it failed saying hosting mode is an unsupported argument, Also terraform does not support High Density SKU.

Comment: Please format your code block(s), logs and errors, in order to make your question more readable, and receive better quality answers. For more information, take a look on this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create an Azure Search Service with S3HD SKU Azure CLI:**

Follow the below steps to create **Azure Search Service** using CLI.

If you select **Azure Search Service SKU S3HD**, it will show as **Standard3 High density** as below.

[image]

**Azure CLI Commands**

```
#Sing into Azure Subscription

az login

#Create Azure Search service with SKU S3HD

az search service create --name  venkatsearch --resource-group myResourceGroup --sku Standard3 --hosting-mode highDensity
```

**Result:**

[image]

```
az search service list --resource-group myResourceGroup
```

**Result:**

[image]

Once ran the above commands **Azure Search Service** with **S3HD SKU** are created successfully as below.

[image]

Refer the [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cli/azure/search/service?view=azure-cli-latest#az_search_service_create) more about **Azure Search Service** using **CLI**.

Comment: I got the error resolved. It was not the issue with code but with the agent running it. AZ module was not installed so it was failing. Your solution worked. Thanks!